# R: Cross reference a data frame with information from a text file

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has one column called activity.num. Each row (there are about 10,000 rows) contains a value between 1 and 8.

In a text file called activity.txt I have a description of the activity. The format of the file is:

```
1. Read1
2 Write2
...
8 Activity
```

My goal is to read this file and append a new column to the data frame called activity.desc with the proper description.

I managed to read in the file

```
# returns a list of the activity number and description
activityList <- function() {
    con <- file("./activity.txt", open="rt")    
    data <- readLines(con)
    close(con)

    # split the list on the space
    data <- strsplit(out," ")
}
```

The resulting output is a list with each line containing a vector with the first element being the number and the second being the description.

I would be grateful if you could:

1. Comment on whether my approach is efficiently correct
2. Help me with the generation of activity.desc.

Thanks.

Comment: Convert your list into a data.frame with two columns (code and description) and than `merge` with your data.

Comment: Aside from Roland's answer, why do you use your technique to read in the text descriptions?  Would you consider text  <- scan(file = "activity.txt", what = "character", sep = "\t")?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution (I'm not sure whether it can be improved upon)

```
# activityList() function is defined above
activityref <- activityList()

# Add a new column with the description. ydata is the original data frame.
ydata[,"activity.desc"] <- sapply(ydata[,"activity.num"], function(x) activityref[[x]][2])
```

Hope this helps.